# Python Multiple Threads with a shared variable

Tags: python, multithreading, global-variables, python-multithreading, shared-variable

I think this question is trivial but I'm having difficulty interpreting similar questions on here. I have multiple threads processing my data sequentially using queuing. That works fine, but I also would like to have a global configuration variable that is currently passed to each thread that I can update when necessary.

for example, in my Main.py, I have a configuration initialized as follows:

```
import Application1 as app1
import Application2 as app2
#App3, App4 also exist the same as App2.

config = {'parameter_1': 'value1', 'parameter_2': [1,2,3,4]}

Application1 = app1.Application1(config, other_stuff, etc)
Application2 = app2.Application2(config, other_stuff_2, etc_2)

MainWindow.start()
processing.start()
```

In my next file, "Application1.py", i have the following:

```
class Application1(Thread):
    def __init__(self, config): #I am currently passing my global config settings as an arg
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self._stopevent = threading.Event()
        self.config = config 

    def run(self):
        do_stuff()

    def join(self, timeout=None):
        """ Stop the thread. """
        self._stopevent.set()
        Thread.join(self, timeout)
```

The same thing happens in my file "Application2.py. In "Application2", I would like to update the "config" variable so that it changes the next time "Application1" reads from it, whenever that may be (order is not important). I thought using global variables can fix this, but I read that using them is generally frowned upon. I am wondering what the most efficient way to do this would be. It isn't important to me what the order of threads read and write to this variable, I am looking for just the plain quickest method.

Please let me know if I should add any information to this question,
Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to share a variable between different threads?

Comment: Yes. I would like to pass my config variable defined in the Main script to the threads and have them share the variable.

Comment: Have you tried using queue?

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I have indeed implemented queueing for passing data sequentially through each thread. I use the "queue.get" and "queue.put" methods. My config 'variable' isn't processed sequentially, but mostly read from the other threads. The reason for my question is that I would like to create a GUI-based thread where user input can update my configuration parameters (the config variable) and disseminate it to the other threads. Is queuing still optimal in this scenario? My knowledge of queuing is limited to the basic get and put methods.